# How can I check if user is still logged in via Firebase phone authentication upon iOS app launch?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using phone verification method via Firebase in my app to sign the user in. When I close the app and relaunch, I want to be able to check if the user is still signed in. I have searched for other discussions/forums and I have implemented a listener, but it's not working for me.

Currently, when I relaunch the app and check to see if I'm still logged in, I set a @Published var to handle UI Flow.

Here is my login method in my view model:

```
class UserManagerModel : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // Initializers
    @Published var loggedIn : Bool = false


    func appLaunch_listener() {
        
        
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ auth, user in
            
            if user != nil {
                
                print("user is logged in")
                self.loggedIn = true
                print(self.loggedIn)
                
            }
            
            else {
                print("user is not logged in")
                self.loggedIn = false
            }
        })
        
    }

    func sendPhoneNumber(phone: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        
        // Send the phone number to firebase auth
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(String("+1\(phone)"), uiDelegate: nil) { verificationId, error in
            
            if error == nil {
                
                // Got the verification id and save to local storage
                UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationId, forKey: Constants.verificationIdStorageKey)
                completion(error)
                
            }
            
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Notify the UI
                completion(error)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func verifyCode(code: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        
        // Get the verification id from local storage
        let verificationId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.verificationIdStorageKey) ?? ""
        
        // Send the code and the verificaiton id to firebase
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId, verificationCode: code)
        
        // Sign in the user
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
            
            
            if error == nil {
               
                self.userInfo()
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    // Notify the UI
                    completion(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

My AppDelegate is set up like this to add a listener for the user when launching the app:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        
        // --- Configure Firebase ---
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // Check if user is logged in
        UserManagerModel().appLaunch_listener()

        return true
    }

}
```

My LaunchView to handle if user is logged in or not:

```
struct LaunchView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager : UserManagerModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if userManager.loggedIn {
            
            HomeView()
                .onAppear{
                    userManager.userInfo()
                }
            
        }
        
        else if !userManager.loggedIn {
            
            if userManager.newUser {
                
                OnboardingView()
                
            }
            else {
                LoginForm()
            }
            
        }
    
    }
}
```

The user is able to sign in successfully and directs the user to the HomeView(). However, when I close and relaunch the user is directed to the LoginForm(), which shouldn't happen. In my AppDelegate I check to see if the user is signed and set the @Published var loggedIn to true, but it doesn't update the UI to being the user to the HomeView(). In my print logs it does show that the user is still signed in and the published var is true... I feel like this is something easy I'm missing but I have been stuck on this for a few days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I explain this in detail in my Firebase Auth videos, for example in [Getting started with Firebase Auth for Apple platforms](https://youtu.be/q-9lx7aSWcc?t=547s) at the 9:07 timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFriese! I believe my actual issue now is that my @Publisher var loggedIn property does not signal the LaunchView to change. My logs show that my loggedin property does change to true from the addStateDidChangeListener, but I can't get it to make the change on the UI / LaunchView

Answer (score -1):

```
var isSignedIn: Bool {
    return auth.currentUser != nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lemonator21! I realized my issue now is how to handle @Publisher properties

Comment: No worries, pls mark answer as correct if found useful.